# Is It possible to create Python files using Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

As far as I have read it seems like Jinja is only for creating HTML files. Can it be used for creating python files as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is not specific to HTML, you can generate any type of file.

For more information, see http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/

> A Jinja template is simply a text file. Jinja can generate any text-based format (HTML, XML, CSV, LaTeX, etc.). A Jinja template doesn’t need to have a specific extension: .html, .xml, or any other extension is just fine.

Answer (score -3):

Jinja is mainly to embed python code into html templates, similar to PHP's `<?php echo "Hello" ?>` if you're familiar with PHP.